# Migrating Established TCP connection with docker containers

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket, docker, containers

Is it possible to transparently migrate an established TCP connection along with the Docker container from one node to another?

My use case is scaling/re-scheduling an web-app which relies on WebSockets but I believe there would be more use cases for other application protocols and plain tcp.
What I'm looking for is a way to do it completely transparently for client applications. I'm aware it's possible to reconnect upon disconnection but this is not what I need.

I've been looking at SockMI agent but it seems to be still in beta and missing documentation.
If I understand this correctly the migration would require the following at high-level:

- Trigger scaling action (when it all needs to start)
- Launch replacement container on new node
- Freeze container's processes on original node
- Put tcp connections on hold
- Transfer the processes and their state across to new node
- Migrate the TCP connection

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transparently migrate an established TCP connection ... from one node to another?

No.

Comment: Kindof expected to get this answer. Thanks